# facebook xfbml usage

Tags: facebook

i am starting to make an iframe based app for facebook. the standalone web app is ready. only facebook integration is left. 
i looked over things in the docs and learned that i can use XFBML tags only. but when i tried using them, it didnt work.
can someone tell me how to use the XFBML tags. also is there any doctype mod to be done on the php page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest taking a walkthrough of the [XFBML setup docs](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/XFBML#Getting%5FStarted%5Fwith%5FXFBML).  There are several requirements to go through before you can start rendering XFBML tags:

- In order for XFBML tags to work, you must specify `xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml` as an attribute in your `<html>` tag.
- You need a cross-domain receiver file (`xd_receiver.htm`)
- You need to include the `FeatureLoader.js` library.
- You need to use the `RequireFeatures` call of the Facebook library to load the XFBML parser

There are walk-throughs available for setting up XFBML if you google around, but honestly that FB document is pretty straightforward.  It's the one I always follow when setting up a new iframe app.

Comment: That link no longer works. I'm finding XFBML documentation *really* hard to find. Has it been deprecated?